# Roslyn AdhocWorkspace asking for reference to System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm trying to do semantic analysis on a bit of C# code.
When setting up an `AdhocWorkspace` for my tests I've found examples that point to using the the assembly location on `Type` and `object`.
When I do this I get the following errors in my diagnostics:

> [0]: TestIsNotInstanceOfTypeMessage.cs(13,20): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>
> [1]: TestIsNotInstanceOfTypeMessage.cs(13,13): error CS0012: The type 'Type' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

When I add the following line everything works well:

```
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Reference Assemblies\\Microsoft\\Framework\\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\\Facades\\System.Runtime.dll"),
```

I'm not really happy with a hard coded path in my test project but am unsure how to "get" the 4.6.1 versions of `object` and `Type` any other way.
The code below shows the gist of my helper to get an `AdhocWorkspace`

```
private static readonly ImmutableArray<MetadataReference> _coreReferences = 
ImmutableArray.Create<MetadataReference>(
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Type).Assembly.Location),
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)


private static readonly Project _baseProject = new AdhocWorkspace()
    .AddProject("Test", LanguageNames.CSharp)
    .AddMetadataReferences(_coreReferences)
    .WithCompilationOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));
```

Some more details:

- `Visual Studio Community v15.4.0`
- `Target framework: .NET 4.6.1`
- `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp v2.4.0`
- The main project is a console application, and the test project is a regular library, neither are PCLs

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you are using AdhocWorkspace. This workspace is designed to be .Net-agnostic as far as I know. Meaning - it should work for both .Net Standard and .Net Core, cross version.

If you want to skip issues related to default libraries, you may be better off with [MSBuildWorkspace](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs)

However, this workspace relies on MSBuild being installed on the machine, and some other MSBuild specific things which is likely to lead to some other issues. Like:

*Msbuild failed when processing the file 'C:\Path\Myfile.csproj' with message: C:\Path\packages\somepackage\build\somepackage.targets: (75, 2): The "sometask" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.*

If you want to stick to AdHoc workspace - you will have to locate the references manually, by using the registry to locate the .Net assemblies folder or maybe turn to the GAC. In other words - if you want to tie the AdHoc space in your solution to the .Net Standard - you're allowed to do so, but you are on your own.